# fail to marshal nested xml elements

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, nested

Im Trying to create an XML from java class with nested element.
I don't get where is my mistake and what should I change
thanks!

my main class:

```
String MY_XML = "my path...";  //hier is the path...

JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(MasterDataRM.class);
Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);

 Master temp = new Master();
 temp.setTransactionStatus("AlmostOk");
 m.marshal(temp, new File(MY_XML));
 m.marshal(temp, System.out);
```

---

my Class to be marshalled:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement
public class Master {

    @XmlElement
    protected Date ResponseDatetime = new Date();

    @XmlElement
    protected Transaction transaction;


    public void setResponseDatetime(Date date){
        this.ResponseDatetime = date;
    }

    public Date getDate(){
        return ResponseDatetime;
    }

    public static class Transaction{
        @XmlElement
        String status = "OK";
    }

    public void setStatus(String status){ 
        transaction.status = status; //  This throws the NullPointerException !!!
    }

    public String getStatus(){
        return transaction.status;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
transaction.status = status; // This throws the NullPointerException !!!
```

Because you are not initializing inner static class, remember all ways initialize instance variable before user it , that's why you are getting **NLP**

create Transcation object first and set it using outer class object as

```
temp.setTransaction(new Master.Transaction());
```

Update your class as like

```
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Master {

    public Master() {
    }

    @XmlElement
    protected Date ResponseDatetime = new Date();

    @XmlElement
    protected Transaction transaction;

    public void setResponseDatetime(Date date) {
        this.ResponseDatetime = date;
    }

    public Date getDate() {
        return ResponseDatetime;
    }

    public static class Transaction {
        @XmlElement
        String status = "OK";
    }

    public void setStatus(String status) {
        transaction.status = status; // This throws the NullPointerException !!!
    }

    public String getStatus() {
        return transaction.status;
    }

    public Transaction getTransaction() {
        return transaction;
    }

    public void setTransaction(Transaction transaction) {
        this.transaction = transaction;
    }

}
```

Marsh it

```
JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Master.class);
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        Master temp = new Master();
        temp.setTransaction(new Master.Transaction());
        temp.setStatus("AlmostOk");
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(temp, new File(MY_XML));
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(temp, System.out);
```